# After upgrading MySQL 5.6 to 5.7, the database doesn't show any error message

Tags: mysql

I don't know if someone has gone through it, but after upgrading MySQL 5.6.28 to 5.7.14, when an error occurs the output only shows the error code without the error message like the example below:

> mysql> select asd;
>
> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown error 1054

Not only is it happening for this error, but also for any other type of error.

I'm using MySQL Community 5.7.14 on CentOS 7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a proper solution to this error, so I've solved it by upgrading to the next release. 
After the upgrade, the error messages, which weren't being displayed, have started to show again.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it's "solved" if the problem is still happening!